# select a JSON element which have no node name

Tags: json, xpath, jsonpath

I have multiple JSON file who have all the same schema:

```
{"q0":{"query":"William","limit":3}}
{"q1":{"query":"Joe","limit":3}}
```

Using xpath or JSONPath I would like to extract each element into a table:

```
|id | query   |limit |
|q0 | William | 3    |
|q1 | Joe     | 3    |
```

I have no problem getting the query and limit field using `..query` and `..limit` but I can'a find the syntax to extract the `id` field (ie `q0` and `q1`).

I've been trying `@*` and `$*` with no success.
So is there a way to select a JSON element which have no node name?

As said in the comment, I am using talend  tExtractJSONField component which use XPath to parse JSON.

Comment: XPath is for XML elements, not for JSON. There is JSONiq (basically XQuery for JSON) and many XQuery processors have some sort of JSON parsing, but XPath won't work

Comment: thanks @dirkk I am using talend tExtractJSONField component which use  XPath to parse JSON. Using http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/ I can then easily convert XPath to JSONPath.

Comment: What do you actually want to get as result in the end? I mean, if you want the root element, why not simply take the JSON as it is.

Comment: thanks @dirkk for following up. I've udpdated again the question with more context and what I am trying to achieve. Hopefully this will make more sense now.

Comment: I updated my answer and the Plunkr. I don't now this talend solution, so I am not sure you can aplly that there? If not, what possibilities are there to do any scripting there, as JsonPath can not do this on his own. By the way, this solution using XPath to traverse JSON looks horrible from a technical viewpoint, sometimes I wonder what software vendors are doing...

Comment: thank dirkk, no I can't apply your code there, talend don't want to understand . only. I've to do a workaround by splitting the row using regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.` you can get the current element. There is no possibility using JsonPath to extract key names. Hence, you can do this in JavaScript by using `for` and grabbing the key name.

The following HTML shows a complete example:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="jsonpath.js"></script>    
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 id="h1"></h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var o = {"q0":{"query":"WilLIAM","limit":3}};
      var key;
      for(var i in jsonPath(o, ".")[0]) key = i;
      document.getElementById("h1").appendChild(document.createTextNode(
        key
        ));
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is a Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/CaZD1lVhr1E2S8VN5vnP

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/ would point to `$.q0`.

Comment: Thanks @Francois, I've spend few hours on this page before posting on SO. Actually my question was not well framed as I am I trying to extract the first element whatever its content. $.q0. is too narrow in this case.

Answer (score 0):

By using Google's Gson library you can read as below.

```
HashMap<String, JsonElement> myMap = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, JsonElement>>(){}.getType());

String id = null, query = null;
int limit = 0;

for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
  id = entry.getKey();
  if(entry.getValue() != null) {
    JsonElement je = entry.getValue();
    if(je.isJsonObject()) {
      JsonObject jo = je.getAsJsonObject();
      query = jo.get("query").getAsString();
      limit = jo.get("limit").getAsInt();
    }
  }
}
print("id : " + id + " query : " + query + " limit : " + limit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Acutally, you can use XPath on your JSON structure using DefiantJS. This library extends the global object JSON with the method "search" - with which you can query JSON structure with XPath. The method returns the matches as an array.

```
var data = [
       {
          "q0": {
             "query": "William",
             "limit": 3
          }
       },
       {
          "q1": {
             "query": "Joe",
             "limit": 1
          }
       },
       {
          "q1": {
             "query": "Bill",
             "limit": 2
          }
       }
    ],
    found_1 = JSON.search(data, "//*[limit=3]"),
    found_2 = JSON.search(data, "//*[limit>1]");

document.getElementById('output_1').innerHTML = found_1[0].query;
document.getElementById('output_2').innerHTML = found_2[0].length;
```

To see this in action, check out this fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/hbi99/zWU6x/

Also, check out the XPath Evaluator here to see and test XPath queries;
http://defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator